# What does Bourbaki mean by displacement in Lie Groups and Lie Algebras chapter 4-6

Tags: lie-algebras, root-systems

In Bourbaki Lie Groups and Lie Algebras chapter 4-6 the term displacement is used a lot. For example groups generated by displacements. But I can not find a definition of the term displacement given anywhere. I also looked at Humphreys Reflection Groups and Coxeter groups book but I could not find it. Can someone provide a definiton of displacements in the context of reflection groups and root systems?

Comment: See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_group), redirected from Displacement (mathematics).

Comment: This article is helpful probably but it still doesn't have the definition of displacement. Thanks anyway.

Comment: "Displacement (mathematics), in mathematics, also called rigid motion or Euclidean motion, a geometric transformation that preserves the distance and the orientation". (redirected to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Displacement)).

Comment: Ah I see. Its not on the main article but the article is all about displacement under a different name. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

A displacement (*déplacement* in french) is a, affine isometry whose associated endomorphism (which is an isomorphism) is a rotation. In dimension $n$ it is isomorphic to the semi-direct product $\mathbf{R}^{n}\rtimes SO(\mathbf{R},n)$ as such an isometry is a composition of a rotation with a translation.

In Bourbaki, *Groupes et algèbres de Lie*, chapitre V, paragraphe 2, section 4, the term *déplacement* is indeed used, and as you should have seen while reading it, it refers to Bourbaki, *Algèbre*, chapitre IX, paragraphe 6, section 6, définition 3.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Any reference?

Comment: Out the blue I have no references for this, as I have learned it in school in class. I'll try to find something in english.

Comment: As often, Bourbaki was one of the references, I updated my answer consequentely.

Comment: Yeah the problem is there is no english translation of chapter IX... thanks

Comment: Don't hesitate to accept my answer if it answers (as I find it does) to your question, though.

Answer (score 2):

The group $E(n)=O_n(\Bbb R)\ltimes \Bbb R^n$ is the isometry group of the Euclidean space $\Bbb R^n$. It is also sometimes called the *group of Euclidean motions* of $\Bbb R^n$. According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Displacement) a *displacement* is an element of the isometry group $E^+(n)$. Note that $E^+(n)=SO_n(\Bbb R)\ltimes \Bbb R^n$ is the group of direct isometries, see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_group).

Comment: Both distance and orientations are preserved so displacements are elements of $E^+(n)$.